# How to animate assembly of DNA bases?

Tags: animation

How to animate these DNA bases that are being added one by one .
How to assemble them?
Do we have to do this with keyframes only, or we have any faster method?

[image]

[Youtube Video [Timestamp: 1:25]](https://youtu.be/TNKWgcFPHqw?t=84)

TIME = 1:33 TO 2:00

Comment: Hi there : ) While asking a question please don't use all caps as it is considered as yelling and it is rude.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please edit your question and write a short readable title that summarizes the content of the question. Also explain what you are trying to do so that watching a YouTube video is not required to understand what you want

Comment: Personally, I would shoot this in reverse. Start with the assembled strand of matching components. and use some simulation to have them drift away.

Comment: @RobinBetts, that was my first though, but failed to do it so far... any idea?

Comment: @RobinBetts, long time I haven't played with PS... wanted to animate a texture UV but does not work.

Comment: Thank you a lot it was my 1st question and I was amazed by the hospitable response, sir, and thanks for correcting my question and suggesting how to ask properly! I'll be careful.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way to do it, a bit tedious because you have a lot of duplications and *NLA* strips to move but it works.

Basically the method is to create 3 linked-duplicated bars, create an action for each one that makes it stick to the vertical bars, push these actions into the *NLA*, link-duplicate these 3 different bars and, in the *NLA*, move the strips so that it delays the animation for each one.

- Create the path, create one vertical bar, give it a *Follow Path* constraint with the path as *Target*, click on *Animate Path*.
- Link-duplicate the bar (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>), in the *Follow Path* constraint change its *Offset* so that it's a bit in front of the first one. Repeat until you have a lot of bars.

[image]

- Create a second bar, put it somewhere above the path, where it can't be seen by your camera at the beginning of its animation, animate it so that at one key moment it sticks to the vertical bar. Then create a last keyframe so that it keeps sticking to the vertical bar until the end of the animation, for this last part make sure that the animation is linear (in the *Dope Sheet* select the keyframes and press <kbd>T</kbd> > *Linear*)

[image]

- In the *Dope Sheet*, press *Push Down* in order to push the animation into the *NLA*.
- Link-duplicate this second bar, in the NLA, move the second bar's strip so that it sticks perfectly to another vertical bar:

[image]

- Link-duplicate the bar, create a second animation in the *Dope Sheet* that makes it stick to the second vertical bar, push the action in the *NLA*:

[image]

- Then same thing, link-duplicate this bar, in the *NLA* move the strip so that it makes it sticks to another vertical bar, and so on:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

One method would be to shoot a Rigid-Body simulation in reverse. This way round, the enzyme comes along and tears the nucleotide pairs apart, and leaves them to drift in whatever force-fields you have placed in the scene.

- The static 'Base' nucleotides are marked as Passive
- The initially-attached 'Hero' nucleotides are Active, bound to the Bases by Rigid Body Constraints.

There are 2 Constraints binding the pairs: a 'Fixed' constraint and a 'Point' constraint. (*Header > Object menu > Rigid Body > Connect*) Their *Enabled* properties are driven by the signed distance of the enzyme, so they are disabled when the enzyme is close enough. The constraints both use the same driver function, using `self`, so it can be copied from one constraint to another:

```
import bpy

def EzRip(self,x_diff):
    
    # the X location of the Empty implementing the constraint
    ownX = self.id_data.location.x
    
    # the X location of the Enzyme
    enzX = bpy.data.objects['Enzyme'].location.x
    
    return(int((ownX - enzX) < -x_diff)) 

 
bpy.app.driver_namespace["EzRip"] = EzRip
```

(The function is then registered with the file.) The `x_diff` parameter is set large for the 'Fixed' constraint, so the rigid connection is broken some distance from the enzyme, letting the hero swing on the 'Point' constraint, which is broken when the enzyme is much closer.

[image]

Once a single pair is set up this way, it can be <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instanced down the strip, along with its constraints.

Forces (Wind, Turbulence, Gravity, etc.) can then be set up in the scene, to blow the heroes away once they are disconnected, and background nucleotides can be scattered in the scene.

When played back in reverse, this can be the sort of result:

[image]

The simulation is cached in this .blend:

[image]

Comment: Finally, you did it!

Comment: I haven't had much time.. I hope this isn't too late .. and I got caught out by the **ing 'Auto' animate button, for a bit.. :D

Comment: thanks a lot, sir!