# How to make a realistic magnetic effect with force and rigid body

Tags: force-fields, rigidbody

I made a force field with -100000 strength and a small cube with rigid body for magnetic effect.

[image]

The cube passes the center of force field and rotates the center.

[image]

I want the cube to move to the center and stop.

So I made a bigger cube with passive rigid body, but the cube is keep shaking.

The small cube supposed to stop when it touches the big cube.

[image]

I want to have a real magnet effect, but I don't know how.

[image]

Comment: since we as "pixel mover" do fake anyway everything ;) ....you could just animate the force and lower it if it comes nearer... always remember: Blender is an awesome tool...but it doesn't always behave realistic and physically correct

Comment: It depends what kind of motion you're looking for. For a 'snap-to' effect, sometimes it's more controllable  to _release_ something, and shoot in reverse.. e.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/193046/35559